# Pandas: get rows with consecutive column values and add a couter row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I need to go through a large pd and select consecutive rows with similar values in a column. i.e. in the pd below and selecting column x:

```
col row x   y
1   1   1   1
2   2   2   2
6   3   3   8
9   2   3   4
5   3   3   9
4   9   4   4
5   5   5   1
3   7   5   2
6   6   6   6
```

The results output would be:

```
col row x   y
6   3   3   8
9   2   3   4
5   3   3   9
5   5   5   1
3   7   5   2
```

Not sure how to do this.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, use boolean indexing using a mask of the consecutive values:

```
m = df['x'].eq(df['x'].shift())
df[m|m.shift(-1, fill_value=False)]
```

Output:

```
   col  row  x  y
2    6    3  3  8
3    9    2  3  4
4    5    3  3  9
6    5    5  5  1
7    3    7  5  2
```

Comment: What if I want specific consecutive values in column x? how do I specify those values? say if I want consecutive values of 3 and 5 only.

Comment: @Jared then you need to use different masks, maybe this should be a different question?